# Google Cloud Storage - How do I copy a specific blob version (not the latest) via the CLI gsutil prompt?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, gsutil

I'm trying to understand if there is a way to copy a specific version of a file to a new location e.g. normally I would do the following:

```
gsutil -m cp gs://my-bucket/foo-bar.py ./
```

But if there were 30 versions, how would I select the 29th, or any other for that matter?

Noting, I don't wish to restore the old version as a first step either.

I'm aware of the -A option to copy all, but wondering if -v can be used to get the URL first then use the standard statement above against the versioned URL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `#generation` at the end of the name, as per the [Using versioned objects](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/using-versioned-objects#access-gsutil) documentation:

```bash
gsutil -m gs://my-bucket/foo-bar.py#12345 ./
```

Note that this is the *generation* number. You can use `gsutil ls -a` to list the generations first:

```bash
gsutil ls -a gs://my-bucket/foo-bar.py
```

Comment: Thanks very much! Any way to link the generation number to the modified date? Not sure if its safe to assume sequentially highest is latest

Comment: @Stickleback: You can use `gsutil ls -al` to show a fuller listing which includes the timestamp.